# Region Lock Workaround

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, samsung-galaxy-note-3, localization

I purchased a Samsung Galaxy S5, Note 3 Neo and Galaxy Grand 2 here in Saudi Arabia. I intend to give the latter two as gifts (the Galaxy S5 is mine) to family in the Philippines. I read online that some Samsung devices are region-locked to prevent gray market transactions. Is there any way that I can unlock these devices so that my family and I can use them?

Comment: Where did you buy these phones? Phones can be network locked, like they are in the US if you buy it on contract from a carrier but I don't think they do that in the middle east.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can get around the region lock by using the phone to make calls for at least 5 minutes using a SIM card obtained in the region where the phone was purchased.

GSM Arena has a [post](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_on_region_lock_you_need_5_min_of_voice_calls-news-7184.php) on this.

The article also notes that the region lock is for countries in the Europe region.